# Why don't standard library smart pointers overload `operator->*`?

Tags: c++

The following snippet doesn't compile and I'm wondering why this is so.

```
#include <memory>

struct Foo {
  int value;
};

int main() {
  auto ptr = std::make_unique<Foo>();
  auto member = &Foo::value;
  ptr->*member = 42;
  return ptr->*member;
}
```

Why is the following (or something better written) not included in the standard library?

```
template <typename Class, typename MemberPtr>
decltype(auto) operator->*(const std::unique_ptr<Class> &ptr, MemberPtr member) noexcept {
  return ptr.get()->*member;
}
```

Comment: This is not an exact dupe, but I think it's close enough.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat That answered my question